# Print an HTML document with content coming from server

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, api

I received an array of objects describing the content of each page from the back-end. I got an object that contains URLs of an unknown number of images. I want to print 2 images by page. Since the number of the pages is identified by the length of the array (using ngFor) I cannot increase it to hold all the images, so the rest of them overflow out the page and get into the next page creating a huge mess. So my question is how can I add pages to hold the rest of the images.

I tried to test if the index coming from the ngFor is dividable by 2, I add a div with style page-break-after-always but it's not working.

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let img of images; let i: index">
      <app-img [img]="i;g"></app-img>
      <div *ngIf="(i + 1) % 4 === 0 && i>0" class="page-break"></div>
</div>

@media print and (orientation: landscape) {
  .page-break {
    page-break-before: always;
    // page-break-inside:
    // page-break-inside: always;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block; // optional. must be sure it is block item in document flow
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Comment: Q: So exactly what is "not working"?  Q: Are you able to print *anything* from Angular?

Comment: @paulsm4 adding new page using page break before is not working, didn't add any new page.

Comment: Q: So "print to printer" is actually working, correct?  You just want to add page breaks periodically (after every 4th image)?  Q: Have you stepped through the actual HTML/JS code in Chrome developer tools to see what's happening?

Comment: It' s calling the div with the page break. But its not working.